# Can Windows Web Server 2008 act as VPN server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-server

I have bought "Windows **Web Server** 2008". I am trying to setup incoming VPN connection but don't find the option for it.

Is this version of Windows capable of accepting incoming VPN connections?

Answer (score 14):

**Web Edition doesn't support being a VPN server**.  If you look at [Microsoft's Windows Server 2008 "Edition Comparison by Server Role"](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-roles.aspx), it doesn't include "[Network Policy and Access Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732217%28WS.10%29.aspx)", which includes "[Routing and Remote Access Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754692%28WS.10%29.aspx)", which is what provides VPN server capability.  Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

To set up VPN/RAS you need the Network Policy and Access Services role which is not included with Windows Server 2008 Web edition.

You could possibly find some other third party VPN solution to use on the server, but the standard MS RAS capabilities will not be available.

[**Windows Server 2008 Edition Comparison by Server Role**](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-roles.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

To setup an incoming VPN connection on **Windows Server Web Edition 2008** type "view network connections" into start menu search and open it up, then press "Alt+F" and click on "New Incoming Connection..."

Comment: Fantastic answer! Works well for me.

Comment: This is not probably like a proper VPN server but it can be what you need in some cases. I have been using this method for years. Here is another step by step instructions http://www.cloudvps.com/community/knowledge-base/windows-vpn-connections but note as there is not File, you should press "Alt+F" to open menu and create your incoming connection. Also, you can set IP address..And this is directly from microsoft http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753616(v=ws.10).aspx. It doesn't say it is for Web edition but it is :-)